# Display the TimeZone Custom ID

Tags: java, timezone

I need to to display the current TimeZone Custom ID (format of "GMT+X" with X between 1 and 23). I try the following instructions but without success :

- `TimeZone.getDefault().getID()` => result : "Europe/Paris"
- `TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.SHORT)` => result : "CEST"

How can I do it (ex. "GMT+2") ?

Thanks in advance
~
Mounir

Comment: In what context do you plan to display this?  Please read and understand the "TimeZone != Offset" section of [the TimeZone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)

Comment: Also, understand that many offsets are not whole hours.  For example, India is UTC+5:30 and parts of Australia use UTC+8:45

Comment: Ok, but I try simply to get the timezone in the format of "GMT+X". for exemple for India, it will be just "GMT+5", and for Australia "GMT+8".

Comment: That would be erroneous.  And what will you do when the offsets change for daylight savings?  For example, Pacific Time in the USA has a -8 offset during Pacific Standard Time, and a -7 offset during Pacific Daylight Time.

Comment: Back to my original question - what is the context?  Is this going next to the output of a recorded event time? Is this going in a dropdown list for selecting a time zone?  Is this part of a scheduling application to pick a future date on a calendar?  It DOES matter.

Comment: This is going next to the output of a recorded event time. I should diplay to the final user a date in the following format (as ex.) "24/04/2013 14:30:27 (GMT+2)"

Comment: The timezone that i should display should take care of Daylight time

Comment: Would you please update your question to show the entirety of the date variable that you are outputting in this format?  The offset will be particular to the date itself, not just the default timezone of the machine that is running the code.  How are the dates being stored and retrieved?  In local time always? In UTC?  Do you need to convert them?  As you can tell, there is a lot to think about with these scenarios.

Comment: In fact, I have in my code something like `Date dateEvent = new Date();` and I want to output _"dateEvent"_ in the format like "24/04/2013 14:30:27 (GMT+2)" (Yes, I want the timezone of the machine running the code that should be displayed)